# Check if an Auto-Submit URL has been flattred

Tags: flattr

There is currently no easy way to check if an auto-submit URL has been flattred by the authenticated user.

The current way is to

- get the thing, which is 1 request
- then get the list of all flattred things of the authenticated user, which is another request and a potentially really big response
- then iterate over the list and match the thing, which is a performance bottle neck

All this makes it unusable for a mobile client like an iOS device. There needs to be a new call. My proposal is:

```
GET https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/flattred?url=auto-submit-url
```

Response:

```
{
  "message": "found",
  "description": "The url has been flattred.",
  "location": "https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/:id"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had mistakenly not documented the "flattred" parameter on a thing - it should tell you whether the thing is flattred by the authenticated users.

So do a [/lookup](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/#check-if-a-thing-exists) on the auto-submit URL and check the "flattred" parameter on the thing it gives you.

We've added it to the documentation now: http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/#get-a-thing